# Trouble accessing a driver from two separate command prompts - "An application is already using the driver"

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, dll

I recently upgraded a computer from Windows XP to Windows 11, and I am having trouble running old programs from the command line. After figuring out compatibility with python (32 bit 2.7.11), windows (11), and Microsoft Visual Studio (16.7), my GUIs pop up, but I am only able to run one at a time.

Specifically, the error comes down to one line of code: `medPC = windll.LoadLibrary('704IO.dll')`. In the past, I have run two programs from two command prompts that make the above call, and have never had errors. Now, I am getting an error window from Windows saying "An application is already using this driver." Each command prompt accesses a different folder on my Desktop that has a python file (e.g. GUI_Box_1 or GUI_Box_3) along with the DLL file `704IO.dll` and other dependent files. The folders are separate and should work independently.

This issue must have something to do with changes in compatibility between Windows XP and Windows 11. I have worked to use the same versions of programs as on my previous computer (python 2.7.11, all of my dependencies are old versions, and I found a Visual Studio that works with Python 2.7).

I believe that when my program calls `windll.LoadLibrary` I am causing the global interpreter lock to stay on, when in reality, it should be released. According to [https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock](https://stackoverflow.com),the lock should be released at some point, but I can't figure out how to force the lock off.

Is there any way to bypass this error? I would like to be able to call two instances of `windll.LoadLibrary` from two different command prompts.

My old computer used Microsoft Visual Studios version 9, but I haven't been able to find a live copy online, even using an internet time machine. However, Visual studio 16.7 is compatible with Python 2.7 and it opens my GUI, so I don't believe this is the issue.